# best practise with optional parts on html rendering

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering of a good way to conditionnally render a list of items. Basically I want to render a warning message, if there's a warning, I want to render message to contain a list of all the problems, here is my current approach :

```js
text = (
 <div>Orange fields are not mandatory, are you sure you want to submit without :
  <ul>
   {(() => {
    if (e.infos.error === "warning")
     return <li>informations</li>
   })()}
   {(() => {
    if (e.links.error === "warning")
     return <li>links</li>
   })()}
   {(() => {
    if (e.file.error === "warning")
     return <li>file</li>
   })()}
  </ul>
 </div>);
```

that's ugly, but I wanted to test something, so another approach I took was something like that :

```js
function optionalWarning(props) {
  if (props.error === "warning")
    return <li>{props.message}</li>;
  return null;
}

....

text = (
 <div>Orange fields are not mandatory, are you sure you want to submit without :
  <ul>
      <optionalWarning error="e.infos.error" message="informations" />
      <optionalWarning error="e.links.error" message="links" />
      <optionalWarning error="e.file.error" message="file" />
  </ul>
 </div>);
```

This is prettier, but I don't like the fact that I have to make an external functions to do that, I suppose the best practise is the second one, but are there other ways to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html), it will be easy to write conditions inside JSX.

Like this:

```
<div>Orange fields are not mandatory, are you sure you want to submit without :
    <ul>

        {e.infos.error === "warning" ? <li>informations</li> : null }

        {e.links.error === "warning" ? <li>links</li> : null}

        {e.file.error === "warning" ? <li>file</li> : null}

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's so much tidier, how did I not stumble upon that kind of example while searching for it is beyond me, litteraly, but anyway thank you (and the others ^^) I'll accept your answer as it was the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Use [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) - the right hand side of these statements will only be used if the left hand side is truthy.

Otherwise, if the left hand side is `false`, `undefined` or `null`, React won't render anything.

```
<div>Orange fields are not mandatory, are you sure you want to submit without :
  <ul>
    {e.infos.error === "warning" && <li>informations</li>}
    {e.links.error === "warning" && <li>links</li>}
    {e.file.error === "warning" && <li>file</li>}
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

You have to be careful to always ensure a `false`, `undefined` or `null` result when your check fails - e.g. if you're checking the length of a list with `{list.length && <Something/>}`, when the list is empty this will evaluate to `0` and React will render it as text, whereas a check like `{list.length > 0 && <Something/>}` will work as you expect.

Comment: I'll use something like that, good point on the left hand side that has to return false, undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
<ul>
  { e.infos.error === "warning" && <li>informations</li> }
  { e.links.error === "warning" && <li>links</li> }
  { e.file.error === "warning" && <li>file</li> }
</ul>
```